# Java toByte() coverts integer to different values

Tags: java, kotlin, byte

Can someone, please, explain following..

```
val randomId: Byte
randomId = 50.toByte() // randomId = 50
```

while

```
randomId = 1149.toByte() // randomId = 125, while I'd expect it to be 1149?
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: That is not Java. If it's Kotlin, then [the behaviour is documented](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-byte.html)

Comment: How would you expect 1149 to fit into a byte, which is defined in Java to be 8 bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supposse you are using scala or kotlin not java. Anyway the problem is byte range goes from -128 to 127 because the byte type is a 8-bit signed type, so it cant store the number 1149

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happen with Kotlin, but in Java the situation is crystal clear.
A value of primitive type `byte` is stored in one byte (8 bit) and can represent a range of numbers between -127 and 128, as @JArgente also said.

If you try to fit a number which is out of that range, you will create what it's called "a byte overflow" error and eventually you will get a total different result.

In your case, the binary representation of the integer 1149 is "0000 0100 0111 1101" (bear in mind that Java represents a bit as a 32 bits value, I have shown just the first two). So, in order to fit your number in one byte, the JVM takes the first 8 bit and ignores the rest, and what you get is "0111 1101", which is the binary representation of 125.

The situation would be even more complicated in case the first significant bit was "1", because the JVM would consider it as a negative byte number and it will represent it as its 2's complement. :)

I am not an expert of it, but as far as I know, Kotlin is run with the JVM, so I suppose that primitive numbers are treated more or less in the same way. Thus, you can expect that the situation is exactly what I explained above.